# Star amps low, delta amps high!

Tags: current

I have a 2.2kw 400v 4pole 50hz motor. If I connect the motor in star with no load I get a current reading of 3 amps.
If the motor is connected in delta I get a current reading of 56 amps.
What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

If the motor is rated for 400 volts with the star connection, the proper voltage for the delta connection would be 231 volts. If you connect it to 400 volts with the delta connection you are applying 173% of rated voltage. The motor's magnetic circuit will be saturated and the current will be very high.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be the reason for this?

One possible reason is that you have a motor winding reversed. Check your wiring.